# Export a method alias of COM visible .NET class

Tags: .net, com, comvisible

I have a construct of a .NET implementation of some utility and a `.WSC` script that instantiates the .NET object. The goal is to eliminate the `WSC`script and to instantiate and call the .NET implementation directly. But this discovered a naming problem.

The class defined in the WSC contains several methods. One of these methods is `Finalize()`. The function name is reserved in .NET since it is used for the life time and GC management. Therefore the `WSC` calls a .NET function with a different name:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<component>
  <public>
    <method name="Finalize"/>
  </public>
  <object id="wrapper" progid="JS.Wrapper"/>

  <script language="JScript">
    <![CDATA[
      // Processes last required steps and closes all logs
      function Finalize() {
         return wrapper.Finish();
      }
      // Any other function
      function Foo() {
        wrapper.Foo();
      }
    ]]>
  </script>
</component>
```

The .NET class implements the `Finish` function:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ProgId("JS.Wrapper")]
public class MyCom
{
    // Processes last required steps and closes all logs
    public void Finish()
    {
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
    }
}
```

There are thousands of scripts that call all the Foo() and Bar() functions. And most of them also calls the `Finalize` function. Therefore it is impossible to change the function name at the COM interface.

- How can the function Finish be made COM-Visible with the name `Finalize`?
- Is there a way to implement two Finalize functions, one for .NET run-time and one as exported at the COM interface.
- Is it possible to implement a COM interface explicitly, i.e. make a custom implementation of the COM interface?

There is an attribute [ComAliasName](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.comaliasnameattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) that can be used to make an property, indexer, field, param, or return visible with a an alias. But it can't be used for a method name. How can a **method** made visible as an alias?

Comment: You can call the C# method `finalize` all lowercase (for example) so it won't interfere with the finalizer. The underlying IDispatch implementation (that allows you to use a C# COM object from script clients) is case-insensitive anyway. Corollary question: why do you need the finalizer on .NET COM objects?

Comment: @SimonMourier Sorry, I don't understand your comment completely. What module should call a `finalize`? Under what circumstances should it do that?

Comment: You could name (not call, sorry) the method `finalize` in the MyCom class instead of `Finish`.

Comment: @SimonMourier I have a different experience with the case-sensitivity of the COM-visible interface. If the calling script invokes the method `foo` and the .NET class has implemented `Foo`, an error is reported: "Object doesn't support this property or method' 0x800A01B6. If the .NET class implements a `finalize` method, how can a call of `Finalize` in the script invoke the `finalize` method.

Comment: Strange. Here is myproject where it does work: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsmmEDGvydk2lCpnt3Lop93BCA8K can you test it?

Comment: Explicitly declaring the exposed interface(s) of a [ComVisible] class is always a good idea.  No problem declaring a Finalize() method, the class can simply use an explicit interface implementation to give it a different name.  Code analysis still produces a mild warning about it, safe to ignore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `Finalize` can be exposed by defining explicitly the COM interface.

```
public interface IMyCom
{
    // Processes last required steps and closes all logs
    void Finalize();
    void Foo();
}
```

It's important to choose the `ClassInterfaceType.None` in the implementing .NET class.
The implementation in the .NET class should specify the interface that is implemented. With the scope prefix `IMyCom` the compiler can distinguish between the name of the method at the COM interface and some .NET CLR internal names. The makes it unnecessary to use a different method name and to create an alias.

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ProgId("JS.Wrapper")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class MyCom : IMyCom
{
    // Explicitly specify the scope of the Finalize method.
    void IMyCom.Finalize()
    {
    }

    void IMyCom.Foo()
    {
    }
}
```

This approach makes it also clear that this is the implementation of a COM interface method.